# Is this reference to ostream a local variable

Tags: c++, lambda, local-variables, reference-parameters

in c++primer 5th edition p393 it is written :

> The variables captured by a lambda are local variables

The book then shows an `ostream` as a referenced parameter, captured by reference by the lambda.
This is similar :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(ostream &os) {
    auto f = [&os]() { os << "Hellow World !" << endl; //return os;
    };
    f();
}
void main() {
    foo(cout);
    system("pause");
}
```

What i struggle with is that here os is not a local variable to `foo`, it exists outside of `foo`'s scope, yet it can be captured by a lambda while "The variables captured by a lambda are local variables". What am i missing here?
Also, why can the lambda not `return os;` ? After all, isn't `os` an object which exists outside of the lambda and `foo`'s scope ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i struggle with is that here `os` is not a local variable to `foo`, it exists outside of `foo`'s scope,

No, it’s local, it does *not* exist outside of `foo`.

The *object* that’s referenced by `os` exists outside of `foo`, because `os` is a reference. But that’s irrelevant here, since we’re talking about *variables*, not *objects*.

> Also, why can the lambda not `return os;`?

It can, you just need to specify an explicit return type, otherwise the return type is inferred as `std::ostream`, i.e. the code will attempt to *copy* the stream, and it’s non-copyable.

But the following works:

```
auto f = [&os]() -> std::ostream& { return os << "Hellow World !" << endl; };
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, so `os` is a local variable reference to an `ostream` which exists outside of `foo` ?

Comment: @user Precisely.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda from above is compiled by the compiler to something similar to **f2** in **foo2()**. So lambda instance is local within **foo2** and the ostream reference (pointer) is a member varible within the local lambda instance.

So you have to make sure, that the lambda with wrapped reference to ostream not outlives the ostream (os) itself, which doesn't happen in this case, because the lambda instance lives only within function scope -> smaller as the scope of passed ostream reference os argument.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(ostream &os) {
    auto f = [&os]() { os << "Hellow World !" << endl; //return os;
    };
    f();
}

void foo2(ostream& os) {
    // The lambda f from foo is compiled to something similar to f2.
    struct f2 {
        f2(ostream& oss)
        : os_(oss) {}

        void operator()() const
        {
            os_ << "Hellow World !" << endl; 
        }

        private:
        ostream& os_; // Note: this is reference, but local to f2 ( == "lambda")
    };

    f2 t(os);
    t(); // call "lambda"
}

int main() {
    foo(cout);
    foo2(cout);
    return 0;
}
```